# moving arrow animation with css

Tags: html, css

I want to make an arrow that moves to the right when I hover over the element it is in.
Right now my both elements move at the same time.(h3 and span).

The arrow and the text must be on the same line. only the arrow should move.
I need to use only html and css (no js or ajax).

```css
.container-fluid .blue-row {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row h3 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 39px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row h3 span {
    margin-left: 5%;
    transition: 1s;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row:hover > h3 span {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="blue-row">
        <h3>Check how we can kickstart your smart projects<span>&#10230;</span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just set ```hover``` on ```h3:hover span``` and it will work.

Comment: @battaboombattabaam still both of them are moving + i need my arrow to move when i hover over .blue-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rule `transform: translateX()` for hover, and preferably for default. Also, make the `span` block using rule `display: inline-block`.

```css
.container-fluid .blue-row {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row h3 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 39px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row h3 span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    transition: 1s;
}

.container-fluid .blue-row:hover > h3 span {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="blue-row">
        <h3>Check how we can kickstart your smart projects<span>&#10230;</span></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```